# Passing an array to a slave python script

Tags: python, arrays, subprocess

I am quite new to python.
I learned how to pass arguments as string or floats to a slave script.
As an instance, here it is the main script:

```
#main script (mainscript.py)
import subprocess, sys
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.5,3.2,10)

for i in range(x.size) :
    subprocess.call([sys.executable,'slavescript.py',
                     '%s' %sys.argv[1], '%s' %sys.argv[2], '%s' %xpnt[i]])
```

And here the slave script:

```
#slave script (slavescript.py)

import sys

sys.argv[1] = str(sys.argv[1])
sys.argv[2] = int(sys.argv[2])
sys.argv[3] = float(sys.argv[3])

...
...
```

Now, if in python I run the following command:

```
run mainscript.py N 5
```

Then slavescript.py starts using N as a string, 5 as an integer and the third argument is converted to a float. slavescript.py is run m times, where m is the size of the array x.

I would like to pass the whole content of the array x at once, i.e. without the for loop in the main script. I think that the subprocess.call can have only strings among its arguments... I hope someone may have time to help me or give me some hints.

Thanks for the attention.
Noctu

Comment: Why are you using a slave script in the first place? With both scripts written in Python, you could just encapsulate the functionality of each script in its own function and call that with regular arguments, instead of using `subprocess`.

Comment: If you need multiple processes, use `multiprocessing`. It's built-in to Python and handles worker pools, IPC with Python objects, synchronization, and a whole lot of other hassles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to use a separate process is if you need parallel processing. If you do need that, then if you're managing lots of workers, use something like celery.

If you do find it appropriate to roll your own, you need to reduce what you want to send to a textual representation. I suggest using the `json` module.

If you don't need a separate process, just import the other python module, and access its functionality directly in code (it should already by wrapped up in functions).

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions. I thought to use this "trick" since I wrote a script to draw streamlines using MayaVi. The problem with MayaVi is that it is not possible to free memory after tracing a single field line. Then, I thought to write a "main script" and, for each streamline, pass the needed arrays to the "slave script". In this way, when the streamline has been traced, the "slave script" ends and the memory is freed. I am pretty sure this is not the best way to act, but it is the only solution I found... Cheers.

Comment: @Noctu Then I suggest you post a question about the code which is leaking memory. It is almost certainly the case that your objects will be garbage collected once you eliminate all references to them in your code.

Comment: @Noctu Also feel free to vote this up and accept it, if you found it helpful.